# Google sheets - search a cell for multiple partial words and return different value for each partial word

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to put a formula together that will look at a cell and return a value based on a partial word, but to do it with multiple criteria. For example:

If A1 has the following in it:
Type of session: Private

If A2 has:
Type of session: Group

In another cell I want to then search A1 for *private* and if it finds it return something, like for example 1. But at the same time, search A1 for *group* and if it finds it, return 2 for example. If it finds none of my criteria, it can return 0 for example.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _manually entered_ desired results there. Also see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Comment: I deleted my answer as I was asleep at the wheel. Thought this was a MS Excel question :-)

Comment: Your answer worked for me! I was going to give it a tick.

Answer (score 1):

Use `regexmatch()` and Boolean arithmetic, like this:

`=regexmatch(A1, "(?i)Private") + 2 * regexmatch(A1, "(?i)Group")`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. And in this case, could I return different text for each instead of a number? and how would for formula look if I wanted to add two more conditions to it?

Comment: Very nice approach.

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Hazel try this formula for your new request:                                                                      =IFNA(IFS(
regexmatch(A1, "(?i)Private"),"text1",
regexmatch(A1, "(?i)Group"),"text2",
regexmatch(A1, "(?i)Other"),"text3",
regexmatch(A1, "(?i)Another"),"text4"
))